Define Peer Group and Calculate Peer Group Analytics
I'd like to calculate the average for each relevant group. Each name has two groups and a value. I want to define what the relevant group is for each name and then get the average of value for that relevant group. The rationale is that I want to make sure there are enough instances for that group to calculate my average to make sure it is meaningful.
My raw dataset:
a=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jack','Peter','Jim','Alex','Dan','Chris'],
              'Group':['A','B','C','C','A','A'],
              'Sub Group':['a','b','b','c','c','c'],
               'Value':[3,5,2,6,7,1]})

My Expected Output:
b=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jack','Peter','Jim','Alex','Dan','Chris'],
               'Label':['A',np.nan,np.nan,'c','A',' A'],
               'Average':[(3+7+1)/3,np.nan,np.nan,(6+7+1)/3,(3+7+1)/3,(3+7+1)/3]})


To illustrate the logic, here is the example, I want to first check if there are at least three person in each group. I first check on Group, if not, go next Sub Group. For example, Jack has a "Label" of "A", this is because there are three "A" in Group, so no need to check Sub Group. For Peter, I first check if there are "B" in Group, there is not. Then I further go check if there is three "b" in Sub Group, there is not either, so Peter has a "Label" of NA. For Alex, by same logic, there is only two "C" in Group so I go to Sub Group, there are three "c" in Sub Group, so Alex got a "Label" of "c".
As for the average value, Jack got the average of "A", which is (3+7+1)/3, Alex got the average of "c", which is (6+7+1)/3.
This is what I have done:
a['Group Count']=a.groupby('Group')['Name'].transform('count')

a['Sub Group Count']=a.groupby('Sub Group')['Name'].transform('count')

a['Label']=np.where(a['Group Count']>=3,'Group', np.where(a['Sub Group Count']>=3,'Sub Group',np.nan))

a['Group Name']=np.where(a['Label']=='Group',a['Group'], np.where(a['Label']=='Sub Group',a['Sub Group'],np.nan))

group=a.groupby('Group')['Value'].mean().to_dict()

sub_group=a.groupby('Sub Group')['Value'].mean().to_dict()


a['Average']=np.where(a['Label']=='Group', a['Group Name'].map(group),
                      np.where( a['Label']=='Sub Group', a['Group Name'].map(sub_group),np.nan))


Is there any more elegant solution? Because I have multiple groups in real dataset and a dozen of values I need to calculate average for.

You can use a custom function, groupby.transform and functools's reduce and partial:
from functools import reduce, partial

groups = ['Group', 'Sub Group']

def avg_thresh(g, col):
    t = a.groupby(col)['Value'].transform
    m = t('size')>=3
    return pd.DataFrame({'Name': g['Name'],
                         'Label': g[col].where(m),
                         'Average': t('mean').where(m) 
                        }, index=g.index)

out = reduce(lambda x,y: x.fillna(y), map(partial(avg_thresh, a), groups))

Output:
    Name Label   Average
0   Jack     A  3.666667
1  Peter   NaN       NaN
2    Jim   NaN       NaN
3   Alex     c  4.666667
4    Dan     A  3.666667
5  Chris     A  3.666667

Note that the order of the groups matters, if you use groups = ['Sub Group', 'Group'], then c will have priority over A for the last 2 rows:
    Name Label   Average
0   Jack     A  3.666667
1  Peter   NaN       NaN
2    Jim   NaN       NaN
3   Alex     c  4.666667
4    Dan     c  4.666667
5  Chris     c  4.666667

You can define as many groups as desired, tanking the example below and groups = ['Group', 'Sub Group', 'Sub Sub Group']:
# input
    Name Group Sub Group  Sub Sub Group  Value
0   Jack     A         a              1      3
1  Peter     B         b              2      5
2    Jim     C         b              3      2
3   Alex     C         c              3      6
4    Dan     A         c              3      7
5  Chris     A         c              4      1

# output
    Name Label   Average
0   Jack     A  3.666667
1  Peter   NaN       NaN
2    Jim     3  5.000000
3   Alex     c  4.666667
4    Dan     A  3.666667
5  Chris     A  3.666667

Variant to keep the original columns (except the groups):
from functools import reduce, partial

groups = ['Group', 'Sub Group']

def avg_thresh(g, col):
    t = a.groupby(col)['Value'].transform
    m = t('size')>=3
    return pd.DataFrame({'Label': g[col].where(m),
                         'Average': t('mean').where(m) 
                        }, index=g.index)

out = (a.drop(columns=groups)
        .join(reduce(lambda x,y: x.fillna(y),
                     map(partial(avg_thresh, a), groups)))
      )

Output:
    Name  Value Label   Average
0   Jack      3     A  3.666667
1  Peter      5   NaN       NaN
2    Jim      2   NaN       NaN
3   Alex      6     c  4.666667
4    Dan      7     A  3.666667
5  Chris      1     A  3.666667

How it works
For each name in group if compute the average on the valid groups:
# avg_thresh(a, 'Group')
  Label   Average
0     A  3.666667
1   NaN       NaN
2   NaN       NaN
3   NaN       NaN
4     A  3.666667
5     A  3.666667   Label   Average

# avg_thresh(a, 'Sub Group')
0   NaN       NaN
1   NaN       NaN
2   NaN       NaN
3     c  4.666667
4     c  4.666667
5     c  4.666667

So you could combine the outputs in order with:
avg_thresh(a, 'Group').fillna(avg_thresh(a, 'Sub Group'))

  Label   Average
0     A  3.666667
1   NaN       NaN
2   NaN       NaN
3     c  4.666667
4     A  3.666667
5     A  3.666667

reduce automates this logic to an arbitrary number of groups, an equivalent to:
avg_thresh(a, 'Group').fillna(avg_thresh(a, 'Sub Group')).fillna(avg_thresh(a, 'Sub Sub Group'))

And partial transform the function avg_thresh in a function bound to a (only requiring "col") as parameter.
Those functions are not strictly required but help make the code shorter.

Hi mozway, thanks for your answer! I have two questions: (1) Is there a way to keep all original columns in my raw dataset? Because I want to add "Average" and "Label" to existing dataset? Is there a way to revise avg_thresh to achieve this? (2)Would you mind explaining a bit your logic, particularly on "out". I looked up "reduce" and "partial" myself already but still want to gain a deeper understanding under this context and I don't know why "map" is used also here.

(1) yes you can join back to the original DataFrame (out = df.join(out), in this case don't define Name in the function). (2) I'll add a description.

You can define a function to do the calculation and apply it on your data frame.
# Function to calculate average based on group or subgroup
def calculate_average(group):
    if group['Group'].count() >= 3:
        return group['Value'].mean()
    elif group['Sub Group'].count() >= 3:
        return group['Value'].mean()
    else:
        return np.nan

Then use it. If you also want it to be done inline here is an example:
# Calculate averages
a['Average'] = a.groupby(['Group', 'Sub Group']).apply(calculate_average).reset_index(level=[0,1], drop=True)

# Reset Label for those groups that don't meet the threshold
a.loc[a['Average'].isna(), 'Label'] = np.nan

print(a[['Name', 'Label', 'Average']])

